# Hibernate querycount query, dont know how to do

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I want to make an hibernate querycount on a table.

I have to values, one string and one boolean

HibernateUtil.queryCount(VoteOnPublication.class, new String[] {VOTED_PUBLICATION_ID_FIELD, FOR_OR_AGAINST_FIELD}, **********************);

my voted_publication_id_field is a string, and my for or against field is a boolean.

What should i put in my second part of the query ?
I first put : new String[] {publication.getId(),true.toString()
but that didnt work.
i think the new String is the mistake but i dont know what to put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wild guess (because `HibernateUtil` is a custom class, it's not part of Hibernate API) but I'd bet on the following signature for the `queryCount` method:

```
public static int queryCount(Class<?> clazz,
                             String[] properties,
                             Object[] values) {
    ...
}
```

So try this:

```
HibernateUtil.queryCount(VoteOnPublication.class, 
                         new String[] {VOTED_PUBLICATION_ID_FIELD, FOR_OR_AGAINST_FIELD},
                         new Object[] {publication.getId(), true});
```

Comment: Thank you that's it, i was totally lost, haven't been practicing java for more than 1 year !